# Etymology for “Mc‑” and “O’‑” prefix in surnames

Tags: etymology, prefixes, surnames

There is clearly a prefix in names like *McDonald, McChrystal, O’Brian, O’Neal*.

What does this *Mc-* and *O-* prefix signify? It looks like *Donald, Chrystal, Brian, Neal* are perfectly fine names on their own, so why is there a prefix before it?

Comment: You forgot to mention another prefix for names, that is "Fitz" as in Fitzgerald. It also means "son of" and it clearly shows noble French Norman ancestry.

Comment: @Paola: "fitz" can be derived from Norman French, true, but that does *not* mean someone with a surname in Fitz- necessarily has Norman, French, or noble ancestry.

Comment: @Marthaª *Fitz* was used for bastard-names, so [FitzRoy was a natural son of the king](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_bastard).  There are also various sorts of FitzWhatevers, like FitzWilliam or FitzCharles or FitzClarence — all originally “illegitimate” children, but sometimes not forever staying that way.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[*Mc* is an abbreviation of Gaelic *Mac*, "son".](http://medievalscotland.org/scotnames/quickgaelicbynames/#simplepatronymicbyname)

> The standard way to form a name using a simple patronymic byname for men is:
>
>     <single given name> mac <father's given name (in genitive case & sometimes lenited)>
>
> which means
>
>     <given name> son <of father's given name>
>
> For example, Donnchadh who is the son of Fearchar mac Domhnaill would be:
>
>     Donnchadh mac Fearchair
>
> which means
>
>     Donnchadh son of Fearchar

[O' is the Anglicized way to write *Ó* "male descendant of".](http://medievalscotland.org/scotnames/quickgaelicbynames/#clanaffiliationbyname)

> The standard way to form a name using an Irish clan affiliation byname for men is:
>     
>
>     <single given name> Ó <eponymous clan ancestor's name (in genitive case)>
>
> which means
>  
>
>     <given name> male descendant <of eponymous clan ancestor>
>
> For example, Donnchadh who is the son of Fearchar Ó Conchobhair would be:
>     
>
>     Donnchadh Ó Conchobhair
>
> which means
>     
>
>     Donnchadh male descendant of Conchobhar

Two common misconceptions are (1) that *Mac* means "son of" — it actually means just "son", and the "of" comes from putting the father's name into the possessive case; and (2) that *Mc* is Irish while *Mac* is Scottish (or vice versa) — actually, *Mc* and *Mac* are two ways to write the same thing, and both occur in names from both countries. (What *is* true is that O' is almost exclusively Irish; despite the romantic notions we have of Scottish clans, they didn't use their clan affiliation in their names.)

Edit: as for *why* the prefix is used even though the prefix-less names look perfectly fine on their own, this is basically Gaelic grammar and thus out of scope for this site. Suffice it to say, some languages are fine with *unmarked patronymics* — names that identify the bearer's father using the *unmodified* given name — but Gaelic is not one of them.

Comment: Indeed, `Mac` is the Celtic (Irish Gaelic) equivalent of the `son` suffix in Germanic languages. There's nothing very special about it.

Comment: [pet peeve]There's no such language as "Celtic".[/peeve]

Comment: There is nothing special about Mc or Mac, but there is (or was) something special about Ó

Comment: "Irish Gaelic" = Irish. Another peeve to pet.

Comment: @Remou: indeed, most languages don't distinguish inherited surnames from literal ones.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know existence of such a usage in a language other than Arabic.

Comment: You assert a “standard”, but cite no authority. Can someone cite an authority/authorities?

Comment: @danorton: there is no standard-issuing authority, and there is no reason that there should be one. The site I quoted is simply using "standard" as a synonym of "usual".

Comment: At least in Irish (not sure about Scottish), _ó_ specifically means ‘grandson’, though in surnames it is better to see it as just a vague ancestral relation (basically anything further removed than ‘son’). And using ‘Gaelic’ on its own to refer to both Irish and Scottish—as well as Manx, by definition—is generally frowned upon in the field. ‘Goidelic’ would be a better term (Brythonic has the same patronymic, of course, but it is _(f)ab_ in Welsh and other forms I don't know off the top of my head in Cornish and Breton).

Comment: Also note (he says, a year later) that the modern Gaelic languages do frequently employ unmarked patronymics, but as colloquial epithets. The pattern there is `<Anglicised first name> <father’s name in the genitive>`, so your example person, Donnchadh Ó Conchobhair, son of Fearchar Ó Conchobhair, would colloquially be referred to as _Donny Fhearchair_, similar to how one might in quaint English refer to him as _Old Farquhar’s Donny_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: note that putting the father's name in the genitive is a type of marking, so this is still not an example of an *unmarked* patronymic. It's Fred Johns, not Fred John.

Answer (score 13):

*Mac*, is the Gaelic for "son", and *O'* means "grandson of". It is found mainly in names from family of Irish origin.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_name#Surnames_and_prefixes) for more information.

Comment: The prefix "Mac" is closely related to Scottish Gaelic as well; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Gaelic_personal_naming_system

Comment: Not O', O (Ó Domnhaill) the apostrophe was due to a confusion with the English O' (of). And do not forget Nic, Ní and Uí

Comment: @Remou Do you happen to know if _Nic_, _Ní_, and _Uí_ are seen in modern naming convention, as it is the case with _Mac_ and _Ó_/_O'_?

Comment: In Ireland, yes.

Comment: I'll add to that, just think how strange it would be to say "This is Maria son of Donal" (not quite the right translation, but to that effect) :)

Comment: @Remou: that's the case if you translate anything literally from other languages. A full Russian name might be "Alexandr Vladimirovich Safronov", but that would mean "Alexandr, son of Vladimir, of the Safron's".

Comment: @Claudiu: I think you missed the gender mismatch in @Remou's example.

Comment: @Martha: oh hehe..

Comment: @Eldroß, most of those come from _mac_ and _ó_ to begin with. _Mhic_ and _uí_ are the genitives of _mac_ and _ó_, and are used when the full name is in the genitive: _Seán Mac Grianna_ and _Seán Ó Grianna_ in the genitive is _Sheáin Mhic Ghrianna_ and _Sheáin Uí Ghrianna_. _Ní_ is a shortening of _nighean_ ‘daughter of X’, and _nic_ is a contraction of _ní mhic_ ‘daughter of son of X’. So S.M.G.’s daughter Mary would be _Máire Nic Ghrianna_, and S.Ó.G.’s would be _Máire Ní Ghrianna_. When a woman takes her husband’s name, _bean_ (‘wife/woman’) is added: _Máire Bean Uí Néill_ (Mary O’Neill).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following quote which could be helpful. It is from David Booth's (1766-1846) book: An Analytical Dictionary of the English Language.

[image]

"Words in ITE very generally denote one of a tribe or nation, and as such may be taken substantively, and have the plural. The Old Testament is full of such denominations, such as the *Hittites*, the *Midianites*, &c. Like the *ides* of Homer, they bore the name of their ancestor. The *Israelites* were the *children of Israel*, as the *Danaides* were of *Danaus ;* in the same manner as the MAC (son) of the Irish, refers to the father of the tribe, to whose name the syllable is prefixed. Such PATRONYMICS (father-names), as they are called, exist among all nations."

Page  xcvii (or pdf page 113)
Source: https://archive.org/details/analyticaldictio00bootuoft