# Why is the letter after "Mc" in names capitalized?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, surnames

For example, McDowell, or McDonald, or McKenna, etc. Is it necessary to capitalize that letter following "Mc"? And if yes, why is this so?

Comment: Related: [Etymology for Mc and O' in names](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/etymology-for-mc-and-o-in-names)

Comment: The same goes for "De" and "Di" in Italian and "de" in Hispanic surnames: the following letter is capitalized. (Though, from what I've seen, there is a mandatory space after "de" in Hispanic names, and an optional space after "De" or "Di" in Italian names.)

Comment: I've come across the name *Maconochie*. I know nothing about it, except that it seems to be a Scottish surname, and that it's apparently never spelt *MacOnochie*.

Comment: The general rule in English is you spell people's names exactly how they tell you to spell them, whether or not that seems consistent with any pattern you've ever seen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As *[Etymology for Mc and O' in names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/etymology-for-mc-and-o-in-names)* says, *Mc* is an abbreviation for *Mac*, and *Mac* is a Gaelic term meaning "son of".  Hence the name McKenna means "son of Kenna", and since Kenna is a proper name, it is capitalized, even when combined with *Mac*.

(Of course "mac" alone is itself not a proper name, and from one view wouldn't need to be capitalized.  However since it is taken as beginning the whole surname, it is capitalized as the initial letter of a proper name.  In this respect, it is treated like English most often treats other borrowed prepositions in names, such as *de* from French and *van* from Dutch.)

Comment: Strangely enough, it's rare to see the Norman _Fitz-_ treated this way: It's _Fitzroy_, _Fitzclarence_, _Fitzsimmons._

Comment: Correction: "Mac" just means "son". The "of" comes from changing the nominative *Diarmaid* into genitive *Diarmada* (and then Anglicizing the heck out of it to get *McDermot* or something).

Comment: Or, for McKenna: the starting name was probably something like *Cináed* or *Cionaodh*, which becomes *Cionaodha* in the genitive, and then the English get ahold of it and it becomes unrecognizable. (But eminently more pronounceable.)

Comment: Re: *Fitz* - It being a mark of (acknowledged) bastardy might have a little something to do with the diminution of the father's name.

Comment: When writing in Gaelic (Irish), girls' names are written with Nic or Úi instead of Mc or O as they mean "daughter" instead of "son". So that, technically, daughters and sons have slightly different surnames. The English version of the name uses Mc/Mac for everybody though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends in part on where the person comes from.  In Scottish names, the second capital is almost always correct - McDonald, MacDonald, etc (but note that 'Machinery' does need a capital H).

In names of Irish descent, sometimes the owners insist on no second capital; I had a colleague whose surname was Macdonald and he was not happy when the 'd' was capitalized.  I'm not sure how general that is.

Comment: McDonald, MacDonald, and Macdonald are all separate Scottish surnames.

Comment: Right. It has nothing to do with Eireland -- "Macdonald" is just a separate name.

Answer (score 2):

Some Scottish surnames do not have a capital.  Some can be spelt with capital and some without.  I was told by a Macintyre, that his name if  spelt with the small case i, it meant that historically they were of the lower orders, but the name MacIntyre, with capial I, meant they were of the professional, or I guess landed classes.  That's what he told me anyway.

Comment: (That sounds very dubious, just FWIW!  folk etymology, sort of thing...)

Comment: I haven't heard that before, but as a Macfarlane I'm disinclined to believe it...