# Moving the lower case ‘c’ up flush with the ‘M’ in the last name MᶜNeil?

Tags: names, typography

Regarding names like *McNeil* or *McDonald* and such, twice recently I have been asked to move the lowercase *c* up so that the top of the lowercase letter aligns up with tops of the other two uppercase letters to either side of it like *MᶜNeil* or *MᶜDonald*, or even so that it sits above them like in *M <sup>c</sup>Neil* or *M <sup>c</sup>Donald*.

I do not recall seeing this done in most comparable situations.

Do you know why some might consider this necessary ... is it merely a matter of preferred style? And is the history of the different formats known?

Comment: Do you have an image you could include with the requested result?

Comment: @Catija I know what he means: the "c" of "Mc" is written as a superscript.

Comment: It used to be fairly common to see the "c" of a name beginning "Mc..." written as a superscript, but I don't recall seeing it like that for a while.  (Actually, maybe it's not quite a superscript; from memory the top of the "c" is level with the top of the "M"; whereas with a superscript such as 1st (first), the top od the "st" is slightly above the top of the digit.)

Comment: @TrevorD sure... I've seen it... but I don't know why people would be so picky unless it was going to be on something special like a diploma or certification that would be displayed somewhere. My (Italian) last name starts with "DeM" and the only requirement I've ever placed is that it appear exactly like that - capital D, lowercase e, no space, capital M... in my opinion, asking for the c to be raised is a bit... over the top.

Comment: @Catija Sorry. I thought you meant you didn't understand what he meant.  I agree that it seems strange for people to be so fussy except for special documents.

Comment: Related: [Why is the letter after “Mc” in names capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/why-is-the-letter-after-mc-in-names-capitalized); & [Etymology for “Mc‑” and “O’‑” prefix in surnames](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/etymology-for-mc-and-o-prefix-in-surnames).

Comment: Related external refs: [Why “Mac” and “Mc” Surnames Often Contain a Second Capital Letter](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/02/mac-mc-surnames-often-contain-second-capital-letter/); [Mac, Mc, and O Names in Ireland, Scotland, & America](http://www.irishroots.com/id4608.htm); [Mac vs Mc](http://www.scottishhistory.com/articles/misc/macvsmc.html); & [The Mystery of Mc vs. Mac](http://www.astro.utoronto.ca/%7Emcclure/Mc.html).

Comment: My name happens to start with McG..  My family has always written the ’c’ high with a line under it.  (we also pronounce it as “Mick”)  but it’s so difficult to enforce in others that i’m completely ok with it “down” and I don’t even notice it at all when it’s not. (I ***do*** notice when the ’G’ is lowercase and it does upset me and I typically fight to get that corrected.)

Comment: Another example of typographical subtlety lost during the age of typewriters http://practicaltypography.com/typewriter-habits.html

Comment: See also https://medium.com/design/death-to-typewriters-9b7712847639 if you like waiting for web pages to load

Comment: Hi Colleen - in what context were you asked to do this?  Do you mean, you are a designer or typographer?  If so, I'd guess that the client wanted an "old fashioned" look - right?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answers! I am designing, and so I conform to the clients needs. I really just wanted to know why, and so now I do.

Comment: I think you'll find that this is rather archaic usage from my grandfather's era - say about 100 years ago. Modern usage does not use the superscript.

Comment: @ColleenKelly If you've now got your answer, it might be appropriate to 'accept' one of them, so as to confer credit points to the respective authour.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the context of the request is not stated. As the actual question is about typography it seems to me unanswerable otherwise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it discusses an arbitrary style request.

Answer (score 28):

I believe this is because the name element (now) usually expressed "Mc" is an abbreviation for "Mac"; at one time, superscript (often with an underline or under dots) was a common [way of writing abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript#Superscripts_that_typically_do_not_extend_above_the_ascender_line) without resort to an apostrophe. This is preserved in the symbol **№** for "number".

You can see an example of this in the signature on the letter below, abbreviating "Nathaniel" (from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Nathl_Hawtorne_leter.jpg&oldid=81146591)):

[image]

Writing Mc as M<sup>C</sup> therefore preserves the original, "true" form of the name in a way that Mc does not (as it does not indicate the abbreviation).

There is also [a discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/typography/comments/1i3pk2/using_small_caps_with_mc_surnames/) about the aesthetic and legibility benefits of the superscript c, for more formal type-setting.

Comment: At one time this style of writing abbreviations was used much more widely that just for names. For example https://archive.org/stream/TheGenevaBible1560/geneva_bible1560#page/n6/mode/1up contains many examples with the superscript printed *above* the preceding letter rather than to its right, like "y<sup>e</sup>" for "the", "w<sup>c</sup>" for "which", etc, etc. The original purpose seems to have been to save space, when paper and vellum were expensive and scarce commodities.

Comment: @alephzero, I hadn't seen/noticed the right-on-top version--thanks for the link.  I tried to convey your point about the general practice extending beyond names with the "No." example. I believe the (US?) convention of using superscript for the letters in 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. is also a relic of this practice, though those aren't exactly substituting for an apostrophe. The "Nath'l" example was just the first clear, high-res, open use-licensed example I could find in English.

Comment: @alephzero, the y in ye is not a y it's a [thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)) and it's pronounced th. It's a lost letter in English.

Comment: @Separatrix Historically, that is true. In the source alephzero linked to here, however, the printed glyph is very clearly a ⟨y⟩, not a ⟨þ⟩. By 1560, an actual ⟨y⟩ was used to represent what had historically been thorns.

Comment: This is nonsense. Mc is read as Mac, without confusion in English-speaking countries today. Hence it **preserves** the abbreviation. The raised ‘c’ only preserves an alternative historical  way of doing this. It is now completely unnecessary except in period drama.

Comment: Man, but that's an excellent acknowledgment letter!

Answer (score 21):

Pronunciation.

[image]

The 'upper-C' is a type of [diacritical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). In the 'good old days' this used to have a line under the superscript C called [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_below). All these tend to alter the actual pronunciation of the name.

All this is to differentiate between Mick and Mack. The 'upper-C' is denoting the [pronunciation to be Mack](https://www.isos.dias.ie/master.html?https://www.isos.dias.ie/libraries/AUS(2)/AUS(2)_MS_Norcia_Irish_Prayer/english/?ref=?ref=) (as is Old MacDonald).

It should also be noted that it is archaic and doesn't really matter anymore.

- MacDonald
- McDonald
- Mc̄Donald
- Mc̱Donald
- MᶜDonald
- M<sup><sub>c̱</sub></sup>Donald

[image: Mc example]

If you really want to get into it, look up: punctum delens, lenites, etc.

Comment: Mc is short for Mac, which is Gaelic for 'son of'.  Although 'mick' is considered Irish and 'mack' Scottish, they have the same root.

Comment: Regarding Mc/Mac pronunciation I think other factors take precedence. See article at http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/joe-mc-what.html?m=1 which says it depends on stress patterns of the following syllables. Indeed my experience (as an Irish person) is that I treat Mc/Mac/Mc-with-the-underbar as interchangeable as its pronunciation depends entirely on second part of the name.

Comment: @Aml Both regions pronounce it as 'mack' (or maybe even 'mock')

The position of the letter has nothing to do with pronunciation.

Comment: @James No necessarily. I'm a McG name holder myself, my surname coming from the Scottish Highlands. We take our hereditary very seriously, and we've traced our decedents back quite a bit (1600s, I believe). My last name is pronounced 'mick', not 'mack'. In our older documents, usually dated from before 1800s, our surname had superscript 'c', which different us from non-superscript 'c' holders despite our names being the same. It also doesn't help that we're from the same exact town in the same exact region and migrated to the same part of the USA at about the same time. Coincidence?

Comment: I have never, ever heard the idea that it was aiming to affect pronunciation.  Someone will have to come up with some sort of reference for that.

Comment: @tucker as someone who was taught Irish for more years than I care to remember I know how to pronounce 'mac', which means 'son of' in this context. It's never pronounced 'mick' and I can only imagine this happened due to people with your surname no longer speaking the language. You can pronounce it 'mick' if you like and you'll be neither right nor wrong.

Comment: @James I think that was exactly my point. It _was_ used to differentiate, but no longer matters. Still, I am struggling to find sources that are not opinions, speculations, or hearsay. I had no idea how hard it is. Maybe I should start looking at Gaelic etymology sites? However, I am sure because when looking at genealogy papers, there was always a known difference between Mac, Mc, Mc̱, etc. If an ancestor had Mc̱, it was likely a relation. Others would need further investigation.

Comment: @Tucker It seems more likely that in your family the practice of (consistently) writing the name with a raised-underbarred c coincided with the practice of pronouncing it with an /ɪ/ rather than an /ə/ in the first syllable. I don’t believe there is any _general_ correlation between these two practices, though. In Gaelic (Irish or Scottish), the nominative has _Mac_ /mək/, while the genitive has _Mhic_ /vɪkʲ/. I suspect the different vowel in the English version may be a confusion of the nominative and genitive vowels in the Gaelic versions, though that’s only my own speculation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't doubt your observation about my family being consistent with our spelling but remember that Irish and English have different languages. I think that one might need to understand the various aspects of the Irish way of writing and take into note things like Fadas, séimhiú, etc. In those times writing was not uniformed as it is today and _those_ traditions carried over, but the initial reason was for pronunciation. Perhaps this might be of some help in clarifying this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_mutation

Comment: @Tucker I don’t really think the actual Irish way of writing such names plays much of a part—in Irish, after all, the names are almost ubiquitously written out as separate words, and there are no _sínte fada_ or _séimhithe_ in the word _Mac_. The following name is lenited in the genitive, of course, but not in the nominative… and it would be fairly odd for the _ponc_ to be transferred from there over to the c in _Mac_. I don’t really understand what you mean by “and _those_ traditions carried over, but the initial reason was for pronunciation”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I meant that macrons are used to alter the pronunciation of letters and suggesting that certain writing habits were borrowed over since there are obvious connections between the Irish, Scottish and English forms of spelling during the times where these might have mattered. I've been going through how macrons are used to alter pronunciations and found that I know little. Perhaps with more research I can figure it out. For the last part, I meant that the tradition of retaining the macron as a form of spelling the name continued instead of its original purposes (pronunciation).

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. Yes, that is certainly one use. Perhaps more relevant than macrons here is the practice, going all the way back to Roman times, of abbreviating common words by replacing vowels (and sometimes entire syllables) with little squiggles and lines, known as [scribal abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Forms). Reducing _Mac_ to something with a dot, line, or squiggle is perfectly in keeping with that tradition.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I think the other answer alludes to this. It might also be worth noting that every time the c̱ comes along, the key word 'transliteration' is not far away. So, maybe a combination of both? It started off as a pronunciation, but over time it changed and is now what it is because of style rather than anything else.

Answer (score 4):

The computer killed the middlce case c, a raised c with 2 small lines underneath it.  It was commonly available in old printing type faces but it was lost in conversion to computers. My family always used the middle case, but I have not found how to get it on the computer, though I have seen a a few times.

Comment: I suspect that the demise predated the computer by at least 50 years, and is more likely to relate to the introduction of movable type. And today with the right software you can put the c wherever you like in a document, or at least I can.

Answer (score 0):

> ... twice recently I have been asked to move the lowercase c up so that the top of the lowercase letter aligns up with tops of the other two uppercase letters to either side of it like MᶜNeil or MᶜDonald, or even so that it sits above them like in M cNeil or M cDonald.
>
> I do not recall seeing this done in most situations.
>
> Do you know why it would be necessary?

You could ask the person telling you...

This has nothing to do with the English language. The person paying you, or otherwise having authority over you, is telling you to do this. If that person also wanted it in green ink in Gothic script, then your job is to do it.

There was never, in history, a committee that sat down and cast in tablets of stone the precise position of that letter "c".

It is a matter of desired style.

Comment: If 'This has nothing to do with the English language' the correct procedure is to CV rather than answer. Nowadays, the requirement is doubtless POB, but orthographics / typography is a grey area on ELU.

Answer (score -2):

Putting in my oar on the Mick/Mack controversy: My family have always pronounced Mc as Mick—although the vowel is elided so quickly that it's really a schwa. My understanding is that it is indeed an abbreviation of Mac, but this is the preferred spelling and pronunciation among the Scots who emigrated to Ireland beginning in the 16th century. And yes, I have always been taught to write it as a superscript with a macron under it, although I rarely see that in type.

An exception is in names where the actual surname following the prefix begins with a vowel, as in McIntyre: in these cases Mc is pronounced Mac, and also becomes the stressed syllable.

(Everyone I know with this type of name identifies as Scots-Irish; I am not sure about native Irish names, but I believe it's not so common: O'– meaning pretty much the same thing. But I have seen the name of the legendary hero Fionn Mac Cumhaill spelled Finn M'Cool in popular fiction, and I would assume here also the apostrophe would be pronounced as a schwa.)

Comment: The stress does not necessarily move with vowel-initial patronymics. _McAleese_ (from _Mac Giolla Íosa_) retains the Gaelic stress /mækəˈliːs/, for example, as do _McAuley_ (and the first name _Macauley_; from _Mac Amhalghaidh_), _MacAuliffe_ (from _Mac Amhlaoibh_), _McOwen_ (from _Mac Eoghainn_), etc. Conversely, some names where the patronymic begins with a consonant have—at least sometimes—moved to initial stress, like _McNamara_ (_Mac na Mara_ ‘son of the sea’), which is varyingly stressed on the first, second, or third syllable; more [here](https://www.sos.mo.gov/wolfner/sayhow/m).

Comment: What controversy? The question is about raising the ’c’ in Mc. Please pay attention.

Comment: As an English person whose mother's maiden name, and therefore that of many of my cousins, starts with Mc (sometimes written with the raised 'c') I have always pronounced it with a sound much closer to 'muck' rather than 'mack' and certainly nothing like 'mick'. It's not exactly 'muck' it's more like a sound without a vowel. When names are written with the full 'Mac' that tends to be pronounced as 'Mack' as does the waterproof overcoat 'mac' short for 'macintosh' but I've never heard anyone pronounce 'Mc' as 'mick'.

Comment: There's a lot of variation in unstressed vowels across English dialects, both in terms of the phonetics (which vowels are distinct, which aren't) and the precise realisation (where the tongue is for each vowel). (As for Finn M'Cool, the apostrophe is not pronounced as anything; it's a non-phonetic spelling, just like most English spellings.)