# Etymology of the "Mc" on last names

Tags: orthography

I what taught that my last name which starts the Mc that the c should be above the symbol =, does anyone know what this means?

I can not really type it out on a key board but if you write it out with a pencil you can see the M "lower case c with = under it".

Comment: Check out the answers of [this similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334927/moving-the-lower-case-c-up-flush-with-the-m-in-the-last-name-m%E1%B6%9Cneil)

Comment: This isn't standard, although there are various ways of writing Mc, including with a single line under the C - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_onomastics#Surname_prefixes). Otherwise, speak to your relatives about how they prefer to write it.

Comment: It's a stylistic choice. If it's your own name, you are entitled to write it however you wish. Nonwithstanding any vanity aspect that a reader may ascribe to it. I know of someone who insists that his first name is "aLan".

Comment: The way "Mc" is formatted depends a lot on the available typesetting tools.  What can be achieved with an impact typewriter is quite limited, while an ink-jet or laser printer can do much more.  And keep in mind that the available mechanisms for typesetting have grown greatly with modern computer-driven tools.  30-40 years ago there were not many typesetting mechanisms, so one was often limited to a choice between 3-4 schemes, but now a typesetting font might have a half-dozen ways to lay out "Mc".

Comment: See [Moving the lower case ‘c’ up flush with the ‘M’ in the last name MᶜNeil?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334927/); the most highly upvoted answer to that question comprises an answer to this one.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question body. The title says "etymology" but the body is asking about orthography.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "what this means"? Whether two lines has a special significance over just one line or none at all? Whether "Mc" means anything? [Although presumably you know that]. Please be precise and explicit in your question: that makes it easier to answer, and it may mean that the community can identify a similar question which contains to the answer to what you *actually* want to know.