# Is there a name for the Mc or O' when used at the beginning of a surname?

Tags: orthography

My daughters asked me what the Mc, Mac, and O' beginnings of names are called. Is there a specific name for that specific part of a surname?

Comment: It's a form of _patronymic_ prefix. [Patronymics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic#Irish.2C_Scottish_and_Manx) refer to a father's name, like Russian _Ivanovich_, meaning 'son of Ivan' or Icelandic _Janadottir_ for 'daughter of Jan'.

Comment: @JohnLawler Why not make this an answer? It's better than the other options.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a prefix, just like for other words. See this question for some more detail and explanations of what some common prefixes mean: [Etymology for “Mc‑” and “O’‑” prefix in surnames](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/etymology-for-mc-and-o-prefix-in-surnames)

Answer (score 0):

It's known either as simply a *prefix*, or, more technically, a [*nobiliary particle.*](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/07/nobiliary-particle.html) (As always, [Wikipedia weighs in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle) as well.)

Comment: How are _Mac_ and _O’_ “nobiliary”? Even the Wikipedia article you give a link to disagrees: “In Scotland, there is strictly no nobiliary particle.”