# 2 Letter Initials and nobiliary particles — how to form?

Tags: names, style-manuals

Given names with [nobiliary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle) or other particles in a last name like

- Bobby von Ahnen
- Bobby d'Estaing
- Bobby de Zichy
- Bobby del Alcázar
- Bobby Le Pen

How would you make a two letter set of initials for them?
Would you ignore the particle or use it?

- Bobby von Ahnen: BV or BA
- Bobby d'Estaing: BD or BE
- Bobby de Zichy: BD or BZ
- Bobby del Alcázar: BD or BA
- Bobby le Pen: BL or BP

Comment: If you allow the *d'* I wonder why *O'* in Scottish names isn't considered to be a [nobiliary particle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246776/is-there-a-name-for-the-mc-or-o-when-used-at-the-beginning-of-a-surname) (unlike *Mc* which is a prefix).

Comment: Until La Belle and La Piana become Labelle and Lapiana, I'd ignore the minor *of* word and go with the capitals.

Comment: To a first approximation, the "correct" orthography is whatever the people who actually *have* such names choose to write. But as it happens, the most recent citation in the full OED for "nobiliary" (underlined in red by my browser as "not a word") is *Of all people a student of Proust ought to know that **it is de rigeur to drop the nobiliary particle** when referring to someone **by his name alone.***

Comment: I remember years ago an announcer on BBC Radio 3 commenting that he had made a solecism by referring to _de Falla_: he should say either _Falla_ or _Manuel de Falla_.

Comment: ... and yet [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_Di_St%C3%A9fano) has 'Di Stéfano began his career at Argentina's River Plate ...'.

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes, at first I thought you were replying to my first comment, so I deleted it.

Comment: Isn't this depending on culture and/or country?